# Rolling out Word Macros to various Users without affecting existing Macros?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Am a complete newbie in Macros and do not find much support in Word macros

I have a macro with New ribbons which needs to be rolled out to various Users without affecting their current macros.

Which is the best possible way to perform the same.

Thanks in advance!!

P.S. Not sure if similar query has already been addressed. Didnt find any conclusive answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code and ribbons need to be in a template (.dotm) located in the startup folder.

[image]

On Windows the default location is `\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP`

Comment: So if I understand correctly, i have to save the document as word macros template and save it in the startup folder?  Would that affect existing Macros in the system

Comment: Your understanding is correct. No it wouldn't affect any existing macros.

Comment: Let me try.. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I finally got a system to test it. However after creating the dotm file and copy-pasting it in startup(word) nothing is getting loaded in the new word. Could see when i open the macros, the template is available. Do i need to enalbe something or add thr template? I believe at startup, it should auto load all the macros

Comment: You need to check that you have the correct folder. Look under File | Options | Advanced | General | File Locations. Also check the Trust Center to ensure that the same folder is listed under Trusted Locations.

Comment: Yes i had checked those points and all is correctly setup

Comment: How did you create the ribbon? If you used File | Options | Customize Ribbon then the ribbon isn't in a template of any kind. You need to either edit the XML manually (good luck!) or use a tool such as the Custom UI Editor, or Office RibbonX Editor.

Comment: You are right.. i had used the Customize ribbon tool.. well more work i guess. Thanks for showing the way

Comment: @AjayGeorge - There is also a tool called RibbonCreator which may help you, though it isn't free. There are versions for [O2010](https://www.ribboncreator2010.de/en/), [O2016](https://www.ribboncreator2016.de/en/), and [O2019](https://www.ribboncreator2019.de/en/)

Comment: Your customizations will be held in the `Word.officeUI` file under `\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office` but the XML isn't quite the same